# .net 5 identity for different types of users

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5, asp.net5

Hello awesome peeps I was working on a project on .net 5 and the system have 2 users with their own admin panel on is for staff and one is for customers, the staff admins can create other staff and assign them roles and permission so doest the customers they can assign their employees any roles and permission. I am using .net Identity and what is the best way to do this? should I add the users in a one table AspNetUsers table and differ them through their roles or is there any way that I can create staff and customer and do all the identity features and stuff on two different user tables?  I am a newbie and am a little confused any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> I am using .net Identity and what is the best way to do this? should
> I add the users in a one table AspNetUsers table and differ them
> through their roles or is there any way that I can create staff and
> customer and do all the identity features and stuff on two different
> user tables? I am a newbie and am a little confused any help is
> appreciated

Since you have already used Asp.net core Identity, you could append AddRoles to add Role services in the Startup.ConfigureServices method, code like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

[Note] The above code was configured to use the Default IndentityUser and IdentityRole model, if you want to [add custom data for User or Roles table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), you could change IdentityUser or IdentityRole to your custom model.

If the application doesn't configure Identity Services, you could check [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), then configure the Identity Services.

After configuring the Identity Services, you can create a RoleController, then use [RoleManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to manage roles. And in the Register page, after the user creating success, you could use the [UserManager.AddToRoleAsync() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addtoroleasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to add user to the special role.

The Users will be stored in the `AspNetUsers` table and the roles will be stored in the `AspNetRoles` table, the relationship between the User and Role will store in the `AspNetUserRoles` table, you could find them based on the `UserId` and `RoleId`, please check it.

Then, you could configure the authorization based on the Roles or create policy based on the roles, refer the following articles:

[Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Adding Role Authorization to a ASP.NET MVC Core Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-role-authorization-to-a-asp-net-mvc-core-application/)